# Debug out-of-memory crash, when OOM Killer kills the process?

Tags: linux, out-of-memory

*Posted as Q&A after finding a solution.*

Working on a simulation code base on Linux, allocating memory succeeds, but later process gets killed by an external signal. Adding a signal handler does not prevent this, so it is presumably a `SIGTERM`. Since the process is killed, a debugger cannot provide a backtrace.

Judging by the signs, and preceding high memory usage, it is probably related to the OOM killer. Outright disabling the OOM Killer with

```
sudo sh -c "echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory"
```

resulted in many programs crashing.

What can be done to find the source of the issue, e.g. to get a backtrace indicating where too much memory is being used?

Answer (score 0):

I observed this issue on Open Suse 15.2 when debugging a crash in a Fortran program. It was clear that it was an out-of-memory issue from the description of the tester, but on my system I would simply see

```
>>> ./run-simulation
[1] Killed
```

on the terminal, with no traceback being emitted.

On my system, the source of the issue turned out to be that virtual memory was set to "unlimited", as seen by

```
>>> ulimit -a
```

Setting a maximum for the virtual memory, e.g.

```
>>> ulimit -v 24''000''000  # in kB -> 24 GB on a 32 GB RAM system
```

resolved the issue by making the simulation program return an error code from `ALLOCATE`, or crash with a backtrace* for unhandled failed allocations (e.g. from temporary variables in the expression `cmplx(transpose(some_larger_than_expected_matrix))`).

---

<sup>* Assuming that the executable was compiled with support for backtraces (compiler-dependent), run through a debugger, ...</sup>